# How do I save information and make it show up on the screen for my Android app?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following code for my Android application, which I have written using the sharedpreferences. I got all of my information from stackexchange, but I am still unable to get the values I save to appear on the screen. Here is my code:

```
package com.example.shivamgandhi.gyrosafe;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

public class settings_page_activity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    EditText ed1, ed2;
    Button btnArray2[] = new Button[5];
    public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs";
    public static final String Phone = "phoneKey";
    public static final String Email = "emailKey";
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    SharedPreferences.Editor preferenceEditor;
    private static final int PREFERENCE_MODE_PRIVATE = 0;
    TextView textView;
    TextView textView2;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings_page);
        btnArray2[0] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
        btnArray2[1] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
        btnArray2[2] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
        btnArray2[3] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button6);
        btnArray2[4] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button12);
        for (int i = 0; i <4; i++){
            btnArray2[i].setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        sharedpreferences = this.getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        ed1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        ed2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView41);
        textView.setText(sharedpreferences.getString("Email", "No Email"));

        textView2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView42);
        textView2.setText(sharedpreferences.getString("Phone", "No Phone"));
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v == findViewById(R.id.button3)){
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class );
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
        else if(v == findViewById(R.id.button4)){
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
        else if(v == findViewById(R.id.button5)){
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
        else if(v == findViewById(R.id.button6)){
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
        else if(v == findViewById(R.id.button12)){
            String e  = ed1.getText().toString();
            String ph  = ed2.getText().toString();

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

            if(sharedpreferences.getString("Email", "No Email") != "No Email"){
                sharedpreferences.edit().remove("Email").apply();
            }

            if(sharedpreferences.getString("Phone", "No Phone") !=  "No Phone"){
                sharedpreferences.edit().remove("Phone").apply();
            }

            editor.putString("Email", e);
            editor.putString("Phone", ph);
            editor.commit();
            Toast.makeText(settings_page_activity.this,"Thanks",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the settings page to my application. I want the user to be able to put in a phone number and email address and then save the two values by pressing button12. Once these values are saved, I want the email address and phone numbers to appear on the settings page whenever the user comes back to the page, which is done through textView and textView2.

If what I've written isn't enough information, please let me know so I can clarify. Thanks in advanced :)

### Edit: I have been asked for the R.layout.settings_page code. Here it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="@string/Settings_Page"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="21dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Begin_Calibration"
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/View_Baseline_Results"
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Test_Design_Summary"
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="@string/Email_Results_To"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="@string/Emergency_Number"
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView2" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView2" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView3" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Home"
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_marginStart="26dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="41dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Save_Information"
            android:id="@+id/button12"
            android:layout_above="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button5" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView42"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_above="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:id="@+id/textView43"
            android:layout_above="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button12" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView41"
        android:layout_gravity="right" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please post your `R.layout.settings_page` code, it may help clarify the problem you're having.

Comment: Your code doesn't look very well. Do you understand what every part of it is doing? If not you should take a step back and learn java/android programming.

Comment: I have learned Java programming. I have tried to learn android programming from various sources, but I have just found that learning by doing the actual coding and watching tutorials as I need to works best for me. I'm not very good at learning comp sci for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a classic race condition. You're mixing synchronous and asynchronous calls to modifying shared preferences.

`editor.commit();` is **synchronous** meaning it is applied immediately, where as `sharedpreferences.apply()` is performed in the background, so it is likely that your calls to `sharedpreferences.edit().remove("Phone").apply();` and `sharedpreferences.edit().remove("Email").apply();` are being executed after the call to `editor.commit();`

If that doesn't fix your issue, does your TOAST Appear when you hit button 12? There is the possibility that the equality check of `v == findViewById(R.id.button12)` is failing, in which case the "preferred" way of doing this would be to do this check with `v.getId() == R.id.button12`. It's uncommon, but I have heard of this equality check failing when directly comparing views

***EDIT***

Also, it should be noted that you call prefs.edit().remove().apply() after already creating a reference to an editor in the code above it (but also use editor.stuff() later), which is also redundant coding and should be addressed, but that's not really germane to your actual issue

> ```
>     btnArray2[0] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
>     btnArray2[1] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
>     btnArray2[2] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
>     btnArray2[3] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button6);
>     btnArray2[4] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button12);
>     for (int i = 0; i <4; i++){
>         btnArray2[i].setOnClickListener(this);
>     }
> ```

Your loop condition `i<4` means that `setOnClickListener` doesn't get called for `btnArray2[4]` meaning your button12 never gets an OnClickListener set. Your loop condition should be

`for (int i = 0; i < btnArray2.length; i++)`

Comment: Just to clarify: You should call commit or apply only once per Sharedpreference.Editor instance, when all modifications are done.

Comment: Also, there isn't a need to remove existing values first before setting new ones. Calling `put` when a value already exists will just overwrite the existing value. You don't need to delete the previous one first.

Comment: I fixed the code so the redundant overwrite part is removed and commit is only called once. I tried to fix the button because the TOAST didn't appear when I hit it, but the change didn't help. Unfortunately I still don't see the TOAST.

Comment: I've updated my answer with another fix for why your code isn't working

Comment: Wow, I didn't know I was that bad at debugging :( . Thank you for the help though, the settings page works as intended.